# Parameter expansion in substitution modifier

Tags: parameters, zsh, substitution

Let `x` be a parameter initialized as follows:

```
x=("drink/beer" "drink/whine" "drink/boooze")
```

Suppose there are also parameters `y` and `z`, with `y="drink"` amd `z="buy"`, respectively.
For each word in `x`, I want to substitute the portion that machtes `y` with `z`. Expected output , hence, is

```
buy/beer buy/whine buy/boooze
```

I though the following code would do so:

```
print ${x:s/${y}/${z}}
```

However, it does not work. The "drink" substrings are not substituted and I could find the reason in the [modifier documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers):

> The s/l/r/ substitution works as follows [...] When used in a history
>   expansion, which occurs before any other expansions, l and r are
>   treated as literal strings

This means, that in my attempt zsh literally searchs for "${y}", which is of course not to be found. Is there another way the accomplish my goal, without using an explicite loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter expansion has its own replacement syntax, separate from the history modification operators.

```
% print ${x/$y/$z}
buy/beer buy/whine buy/boooze
```